# Django auth - success and failure result in same behavior

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm following some basic Django auth tutorials. I've got the following in my views.py:

```
def login(request, onsuccess='/', onfail='/login/'):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_to_response('login.html', {'method': 'get'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST.get('username'), password=request.POST.get('password'))
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(onsuccess)
        else:
            return redirect(onfail)
```

I know the GET/POST logic is working because I had another return_to_render statement after post, to send 'method': 'post' to the view, in an attempt to debug. I'm just printing that value in the view so I can see either GET or POST depending on the state.

When I replaced that with the authenticate logic, it seems not to be returning a valid user object because I get redirected back to login. I tried to authenticate from the shell and it worked fine.

Any thoughts on what else I can do to debug?

Comment: Yes check what's in `request.POST`. Are the credentials there and do they correspond to what's in the db? And read up on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: yea that was it - dumb mistake. copy/pasted username / input form elements from a tut and didn't realize they had no name attributes, thus nothing was coming to my POST via the names I thought were there. I know better. If you want to post your comment in a reply, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes check what's in request.POST. Are the credentials there and do they correspond to what's in the db? And read up on [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).